# Completing an unattended to apple cider vinegar

Tags: fermentation

Two and a half months ago, I started making apple cider vinegar using apples, honey and water; all were organic, filtered and no metallic utensils were used. I did, however, added a small piece of a cinnamon stick and some cloves for flavor. Covered it a,, with cheese cloth and forgot about it until tonight.

When I uncovered the cheese cloth I saw part of the top surface was covered with some stuff that I have a hard time  describing and for the longest time I hesitated whether or not to even bother with it; I thought it may be mold. In the end I strained it through clean cheesecloth to another clean glass container. I tasted it even before straining, it was very very tart but didn't have any other flavor that would alert me to mold, mildew or anything like it.  It also smells like vinegar.

My questions are:

1. How should I proceed?
2. Is it possible it was moldy and I just didn't recognize it; it's my first attempt at making ACV.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can mold grow in vinegar?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/92317/can-mold-grow-in-vinegar)

Comment: Honey and water have no place in making cider vinegar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making your own cider vinegar, you might want to be come familiar with what you are likely to see by doing some research first.

I have to assume that you are referring to the "[mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_vinegar)" which is a standard, normal part of the vinegar fermentation process. Say hello to *acetobacter*, they are doing the work you require. Even if they do look a bit slimy and disturbing *en masse.*